# Bootstrap is not styling anything with Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap for the first time and it is not styling anything. I have already applied the answers from [Bootstrap is not styling anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218369/bootstrap-is-not-styling-anything)
and still no luck.

I have `@import "bootstrap";` in my stylesheet

I also have the appropriate gems in my Gemfile. Here it is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development,:test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end



gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
end
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: Rails 4 does not use an `assets` group in your Gemfile. That might be a good place to start.

Comment: Isn't there normally a step to initialize the gem. Where you go like rake bootstrap:init or something similar. This usually sets up your application layout to use the bootstrap template, etc.

Comment: I got rid of `assets` and still no luck. Sorry CarlosCervantes, I'm not experienced enough to fill in the blank.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add 
`config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)` 
to application.rb (inside the class)

2) Add `@import 'bootstrap';` to the top line of a new CSS file.

Comment: Where exactly do I find application.rb? I created a new CSS file by creating a new folder in app/assets/stylesheets called application.css.scss. Is this the correct way?

Comment: 1 - config/application.rb
2 - did you make a folder or a file? (application.css should already be present there). Make sure its a file, and don't use the name already taken. Any name will  do. The asset pipeline will include your new CSS file automagically.

Comment: I double checked and it is a file (sorry about that). The file is application.css.scss, not application.css. I also added config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif) to config/application.rb (inside class) and now it says "this webpage is unavailable" on localhost:3000

Comment: Restart your server, try again. Also, you're struggling a bit with the new CSS file. Rails creates two files which combine other files: application.js and application.css (it may be application.css.scss, not important). Putting code in these files is not recommended. You need to make a new CSS file in your assets/stylesheets ('myapp.css.scss') and add the @import 'bootstrap'; to the top. You can check out chapter 5 of the Hartl tutorial, he runs through the process of setting up BS.

Comment: I restarted the server, removed any codes on: application.js and application.css.scss. I have added @import 'bootstrap'; to a new file called custom.css.scss as directed in Hartl's tutorial. Still no luck whatsoever. I'm not getting errors at all, the damn styling just won't change.

Comment: Don't remove all the code on application.js/css! It should have some default code, which tells it to look for other files to compile to it. If they are empty it will not work for sure. Also, did you remove asset groups from your gemfile? They don't work in Rails 4 anymore.

Comment: I removed asset groups from my gemfile. I do have stuff in my application.js. It starts with this: 
`// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.` and continues on with other stuff that I can't fit here.

My application.css.scss is empty though. What needs to be in there?

Comment: You can easily find this out for yourself. Make a new rails app and see what is automatically generated.

Comment: I have tried to reinstall from scratch 4 times already. I think that when I try and start over some files are left behind and mess up any changed that I am trying to make. Is there a way I can make sure that everything is deleted before I reinstall RoR and Bootstrap?

Comment: You don't need to uninstall RoR; once you have it, you have access to commands through a CLI. If you're using Mac or Linux, go to your terminal and type: 'rails new myappname'

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 does not use an assets group in Gemfile, So remove that & then edit your application.css to include following:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";

@import "bootstrap";
```

**Note**: "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"

Now add require Bootstrap Javascripts in app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery

//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```